# Ways to divide number into two factors

Tags: combinatorics

Given the prime number decomposition of any number, what are the ways to factorise it into two different factors.

In general, can someone point to theory related to splitting a group of repeating people into subgroups.

Comment: You can also get the proof of what Rory daulton said...here...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543081/proving-the-result-of-finding-the-number-of-ways-in-which-n-can-be-resolved-as/1543118#1543118

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you are talking about natural numbers greater than one and positive factors.

Lets say that the prime decomposition is $p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{a_n}$ where of course $n\in\Bbb N$, $n\ge 1$, and for all $a_k$, $a_k\in\Bbb N$, $a_k\ge 1$.

All the divisors of this number can be expressed with the same primes and with exponents between $0$ and $a_k$ inclusive. This means the total number of factors is $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots (a_n+1)$.

If that number is odd, the original number was a square. A factorization that you want uses two of the factors, except for the expression of the number as a square which uses only one. Thus the number of desired factorizations is

$$\frac{(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots (a_n+1)+1}2$$

If that number is even, the original number is not a square, and we get the number

$$\frac{(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots (a_n+1)}2$$

Your last question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks Rory. This is very helpful. By last question, I am generalising the problem, lets say split in 3 groups, 4 groups and so on.